# Embedded SQL Firebird batch update OutOfMemoryError with Java SE

Tags: java, profiling, firebird, out-of-memory

I'm having a big problem with the embedded firebird database engine and Java SE.
I'm currently developing a filtering tool for users to filter out data.
So I have made two Options for filtering, user can chose one or both:

1. Filter out from a black list(the black list is controled by user).
2. Filter out according to a massive list that records every record ever uploaded and filtered out.

The data the user uploads its in plain text comma or token separated like this:

```
(SET OF COLUMNS)| RECORD TO FILTER |
0-MANY COLUMNS  |       ABC2       |
0-MANY COLUMNS  |       ABC5       |
```

When I Upload it to the DB, I add A FLAG for every filter

```
(SET OF COLUMNS) | RECORD TO FILTER | FLAG FOR FIlTER A | FLAG FOR FILTER B  |
0-MANY COLUMNS   |       ABC2       |                   |                    |
0-MANY COLUMNS   |       ABC5       |                   |                    |
```

So, when it comes to the second filter, the program has a main empty table on the first run of the software, then it fills that table with all the records from the very first upload.
The main table will have unique records like the following table after a few text uploads made by the user:

```
 Record |      Date criteria for filtering      |
 ABC1   | 08/11/2012:1,07/11/2012:3,06/11/2012:5|
 ABC2   | 05/11/2012:1,04/11/2012:0,03/11/2012:0|
 ABC3   | 12/11/2012:3,11/11/2012:0,10/11/2012:0|
 ABC4   | 12/11/2012:1,11/11/2012:0,10/11/2012:0|
 ABC5   | 12/11/2012:3,11/11/2012:0,10/11/2012:3|
 ABC9   | 11/11/2012:3,10/11/2012:1,09/11/2012:0|
```

When the data is processed, for example, the software updates both, the main table and the user table:

```
(SET OF COLUMNS| RECORD TO FILTER | FLAG FOR FIlTER A | FLAG FOR FILTER B  |
0-MANY COLUMNS |       ABC4       |                   |                    | 
0-MANY COLUMNS |       ABC9       |                   |                    |
```

So the main table will update:

```
 Record |      Day criteria for filtering      |
 ABC1   | 08/11/2012:1,07/11/2012:3,06/11/2012:5|
 ABC2   | 05/11/2012:1,04/11/2012:0,03/11/2012:0|
 ABC3   | 12/11/2012:3,11/11/2012:0,10/11/2012:0|
 ABC4   | 12/11/2012:1,11/11/2012:0,10/11/2012:0| ->12/11/2012:2,11/11/2012:0,10/11/2012:0
 ABC5   | 12/11/2012:3,11/11/2012:0,10/11/2012:3|
 ABC9   | 11/11/2012:3,10/11/2012:1,09/11/2012:0| ->12/11/2012:1,11/11/2012:3,10/11/2012:1
```

If in the last three days the data criteria event has reached more than four, the user table will flag filter B. Notice that each date has an integer next to it.

```
(SET OF COLUMNS)| RECORD TO FILTER | FLAG FOR FIlTER A | FLAG FOR FILTER B  |
 0-MANY COLUMNS |       ABC4       |                   |                    | 
 0-MANY COLUMNS |       ABC9       |                   |          X         |
```

Both updates are in a single transaction, the problem is that when the user uploads more than 800,000 records my program throws the following exception in the while loop.
I use StringBuilder parsing and append methods for maximun performance on the mutable days string.

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Here it's my code, I use five days:

```
FactoriaDeDatos factoryInstace = FactoriaDeDatos.getInstance();
Connection cnx = factoryInstace.getConnection();
cnx.setAutoCommit(false);
PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
ResultSet rs=null;
pstmt = cnx.prepareStatement("SELECT CM.MAIL,CM.FECHAS FROM TCOMERCIALMAIL CM INNER JOIN TEMPMAIL TMP ON CM.MAIL=TMP."+colEmail);
rs=pstmt.executeQuery();
pstmtDet = cnx.prepareStatement("ALTER INDEX IDX_MAIL INACTIVE");
pstmtDet.executeUpdate();
pstmtDet = cnx.prepareStatement("SET STATISTICS INDEX IDX_FECHAS");
pstmtDet.executeUpdate();
pstmtDet = cnx.prepareStatement("ALTER INDEX IDX_FECHAS INACTIVE");
pstmtDet.executeUpdate();
pstmtDet = cnx.prepareStatement("SET STATISTICS INDEX IDX_FECHAS");
pstmtDet.executeUpdate();
sql_com_local_tranx=0;
int trxNum=0;
int ix=0;
int ixE1=0;
int ixAc=0;
StringBuilder sb;
StringTokenizer st;
String fechas;
int pos1,pos2,pos3,pos4,pos5,pos6,pos7,pos8,pos9;
StringBuilder s1,s2,sSQL,s4,s5,s6,s7,s8,s9,s10;
long startLoop = System.nanoTime();

long time2 ;
boolean ejecutoMax=false;
//int paginador_sql=1000;
//int trx_ejecutada=0;
sb=new StringBuilder();
s1=new StringBuilder();
s2=new StringBuilder();
sSQL=new StringBuilder();
s4=new StringBuilder();
s6=new StringBuilder();
s8=new StringBuilder();
s10=new StringBuilder();
while(rs.next()){
   //De aqui
   actConteoDia=0;
   sb.setLength(0);
   sb.append(rs.getString(2));
   pos1= sb.indexOf(":",0);  
   pos2= sb.indexOf(",",pos1+1);  
   pos3= sb.indexOf(":",pos2+1);  
   pos4= sb.indexOf(",",pos3+1);  
   pos5= sb.indexOf(":",pos4+1);
   pos6= sb.indexOf(",",pos5+1);
   pos7= sb.indexOf(":",pos6+1);
   pos8= sb.indexOf(",",pos7+1);
   pos9= sb.indexOf(":",pos8+1);
   s1.setLength(0);
   s1.append(sb.substring(0, pos1));
   s2.setLength(0);
   s2.append(sb.substring(pos1+1, pos2));
   s4.setLength(0);
   s4.append(sb.substring(pos3+1, pos4));
   s6.setLength(0);
   s6.append(sb.substring(pos5+1, pos6));
   s8.setLength(0);
   s8.append(sb.substring(pos7+1, pos8));
   s10.setLength(0);
   s10.append(sb.substring(pos9+1));
   actConteoDia=Integer.parseInt(s2.toString());
   actConteoDia++;
   sb.setLength(0);
   //sb.append(s1).a
   if(actConteoDia>MAXIMO_LIMITE_POR_SEMANA){
      actConteoDia=MAXIMO_LIMITE_POR_SEMANA+1;
   }
   sb.append(s1).append(":").append(actConteoDia).append(",").append(rs.getString(2).substring(pos2+1, rs.getString(2).length()));
   //For every date record it takes aprox 8.3 milisec by record

   sSQL.setLength(0);
   sSQL.append("UPDATE TCOMERCIALMAIL SET FECHAS='").append(sb.toString()).append("' WHERE MAIL='").append(rs.getString(1)).append("'");

   pstmtDet1.addBatch(sSQL.toString());
   //actConteoDia=0;
   //actConteoDia+=Integer.parseInt(s2.toString());
   actConteoDia+=Integer.parseInt(s4.toString());
   actConteoDia+=Integer.parseInt(s6.toString());
   actConteoDia+=Integer.parseInt(s8.toString());
   actConteoDia+=Integer.parseInt(s10.toString());
   if(actConteoDia>MAXIMO_LIMITE_POR_SEMANA){
      sSQL.setLength(0);
      sSQL.append("UPDATE TEMPMAIL SET DIASLIMITE='S' WHERE ").append(colEmail).append("='").append(rs.getString(1)).append("'");
      pstmtDet.addBatch(sSQL.toString());
   }

   sql_com_local_tranx++;

   if(sql_com_local_tranx%2000==0 || sql_com_local_tranx%7000==0  ){
      brDias.setString("PROCESANDO "+sql_com_local_tranx);
      pstmtDet1.executeBatch();
      pstmtDet.executeBatch();

   }
   if(sql_com_local_tranx%100000==0){
       System.gc();
       System.runFinalization();
   }
}

pstmtDet1.executeBatch();
pstmtDet.executeBatch();
cnx.commit();
```

I've made telemetry tests so I can trace where the problem lies.
The big while it's the problem, I think, but I don't know where the problem may exactly be.
I'm adding some images of the telemtry tests, please I need to interpretate them properly.

The gc becomes inverse to the time the jvm to keep objects alive:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/849/66780403.png

The memory heap goes from 50 MB to 250 MB, the used heap reaches the 250 MB creating the outOfMemory exception:

50 MB
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/94/52169259.png

REACHING 250 MB
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/706/91313357.png

OUT OF MEMORY
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/825/79083069.png

The final stack of objetcts generated ordered by LiveBytes:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/546/95529690.png

Any help, suggestion, answer will be vastly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `PreparedStatement` as if it is a `Statement`, as you are calling `addBatch(string)`. The [javadoc of this method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#addBatch%28java.lang.String%29) says:

> Note:This method cannot be called on a PreparedStatement or CallableStatement.

This comment was added with JDBC 4.0, before that it said the method was optional. The fact that Jaybird allows you to call this method on `PreparedStatement` is therefor a bug: I created issue [JDBC-288](http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/JDBC-288) in the Jaybird tracker.

Now to the cause of the `OutOfMemoryError`: When you use `addBatch(String)` on the `PreparedStatement` implementation of Jaybird (`FBPreparedStatement`), it is added to a list internal to the `Statement` implementation (`FBStatement`). In case of `FBStatement`, when you call `executeBatch()`, it will execute all statements in this list and then clear it. In `FBPreparedStatement` however `executeBatch()` is overridden to execute the originally prepared statement with batch parameters (in your example it won't do anything, as you never actually add a PreparedStatement-style batch). It will **never** execute the statements you added with `addBatch(String)`, but it will also **not clear** the list of statements in `FBStatement` and that is most likely the cause of your `OutOfMemoryError`.

Based on this, the solution should be to create a `Statement` using `cnx.createStatement` and use that to execute your queries, or investigate if you could benefit from using one or more `PreparedStatement` objects with a parameterized query. It looks like you should be able to use two separate PreparedStatements, but I am not 100% sure; the added benefit would be protection against SQL injection and a minor performance improvement.

### Addendum

This issue has been fixed [since Jaybird 2.2.2](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/drivers_documentation/java/2.2.15/release_notes.html#changes-and-fixes-in-jaybird-2.2.2)

*Full disclosure: I am the developer of the Jaybird / Firebird JDBC driver.*

Comment: Thanks for creating the Issue on the Firebird tracker. I can't access it from my job ._. I will tackle my problem with your suggestions, thanks!!!

Comment: Ok... So, I have changed my prepared statement objects to Statement objects but the update time it's painfully slow, and it's just running one of the two updates in the while loop because the records did not reached the criteria for the update on the uploaded user table, so in extreme cases it will be twice as slow. I really don't understand when you say "It will never execute the statements you added with addBatch(String)" why? You mean that with the Statement object the table is actually updating at such slow speed?

Comment: I meant that when you use a `PreparedStatement` the queries submitted with `addBatch(String)` were never executed. BTW: Define slow: You are executing 2000 queries at a time, and looking at the fact that you request a garbage collect every 100000 rows, I assume we aren't talking about a small number of queries.

Comment: Slow means like 8000 rows updated in 2 minutes. I insert 8,000,000 rows into the DB from a file in that time lapse. I do the garabage collection every 1,000,000 rows because I can guess that upper classes will handle their objects in a timely and ordered manner, I can be wrong here.

Comment: Updates in Firebird are more expensive than inserts. A quick and dirty test (single threaded) with 1,000,000 records on my dev machine has 6732 inserts/s, but only 974 updates/s.

Comment: Wow, the proportion is 100/14. Is there anyway I can speed the updates? I have read about some options: I know some DB engines have an internal RowID for very row. Hence, when you use it in a WHERE condition it's faster, but I just can't find that option in Firebird. Another option, is changing the PLAN the update uses, unfortunately, the PLAN documentation for almost every DB engine is nonexistant and almost no one seems to care about explaing how it works or how to override it.

Comment: There is `RDB$DB_KEY` as a row identifier, but I don't think that will be faster and it isn't useful in your case as they aren't stable outside a transaction. Using more than one thread to do updates might speed it up a bit (but too many on the same table will slow down due to lock contention etc) but as far as I know the difference between inserts and updates mostly has to do with the MVCC architecture of Firebird.

Comment: BTW: My test updates all records one-by-one in a single transaction, if I update only half then numbers improve. This has probably got to do how Firebird reserves and allocates space for new versions of a record.

Comment: In my test I randomized the order of records between insert and update, if I update records in the same order as the insert, then updates are slightly faster than insert (probably because Firebird can take better advantage of the pagecache).

Comment: I guess it would be better to create additional questions on SO for other issues (or for your question about PLAN).

Comment: I commented the part where I make the indexes inactive and I have added this to the updates: PLAN(TCOMERCIALMAIL INDEX(IDX_MAIL)) ROWS 1 from what I understand that I'm overrideing the plan, that in standard conditions its making a full scan on the table, I express that I want to find my record using the index and I limit the update to just one row by **ROWS 1** because the table has unique values. The average speed is 2000 updates per 6 seconds. It's still quite slow, I will put the whole result set on a temporal .txt file. With all this findings I'm changing the whole scope of this method.

Comment: You're right Mark, I should create another thread. I will upvote your answer and take it as the valid answer for my question. Thanks for creating the issue I hope it gets solved in newer versions. Thanks!!!

Comment: @jRam90 I already committed a fix to disallow calls to these methods in `Prepared` and `CallableStatement` : http://sourceforge.net/p/firebird/code/57463/ Jaybird 2.2.2 will probably be released in January.

Answer (score 1):

do not execute batch statements while iterating through the result set. store the sql you want to execute in a collection and then when you have finished processing the result set
start executing the new sql. does everything have to happen inside the same transaction?

Comment: Well, not necessarily. Nice approach, I will try it. The thing is, how to mantain 2 000 000 updates in memory collections? I've tried using arrays and the memory heap just can't take such amount of strings.

Comment: Iterating over a resultset while adding batch shouldn't be a problem. The thing I see that is potentially a problem are using a `PreparedStatement` as if it is `Statement`. It looks more like Jaybird doesn't clear the list of batched statements after an execute; I will check the code tonight.

Comment: BevynQ You were right, iterating the result set into a temporal .txt file and then using the text file as source to iterate the batch updates makes it faster. I have to state again that using the PLAN statement with the index and limiting the update to only one helps, using the Stament Object is the only way of doing batch updates according to Mark Rotteveel.

Comment: ideally you would do this in an update command but 2000000 rows might be a bit too much for the database. Systems will usually do such an update in chunks that can be restarted. Do not know if that is an option for you.

Comment: you could consider a user defined function or trigger to do the string manipulation. Also batch statements are dependent on the driver not all drivers support them(some appear to by cheating).

Comment: The user can have a list from 1 user to 11,000,000 users updated. The usage of a temporal text file with batch statements fits my case. However, it will take some time to make such an inmense update. I've closed the project yesterday, for good, I hope. This little piece of software, got me thinking, how far can a DB can hold efficiently in an standard PC.